# LoadListingInformationAsync: 0x80190194 Not found (404)

Tags: c++, uwp, in-app-purchase, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

We have submitted a UWP app, built using the Windows 8.1 SDK, to the Windows Store, published with the 'Private Audience' option. We observe that `LoadListingInformationAsync` (in the `CurrentApp` class) throws a `0x80190194 Not found (404)` exception.

This happens regardless whether we run the project in Visual Studio or whether we install the Store version. The In-App products have been added, published and are all marked with 'In The Store'. We have checked that all the identifiers/names listed under 'App management/Identity details' match those in the manifest. We have checked that the In-App-Code works as expected with the `CurrentAppSimulator`. We have also used a network traffic monitor to check for network errors and haven't found any.

We have posted the same issue in the windows forum where it was suggested by a Microsoft employee to simply wait a couple of days. It is now two weeks since our in-app-products were published in the dashboard. This problem is blocking us completely and we definitely need help in fixing this issue.

Therefore we would very much appreciate if someone at Microsoft could find out why the in-apps published in the dashboard apparently haven't been installed correctly in the store and thus aren't visible from our application.

Here is our Package SID:

```
S-1-15-2-2762217728-2497590674-2702625719-1901796822-1169495103-2187450542-4267134542
```

Comment: You could create a [support ticket](http://aka.ms/storesupport) through your developer account to report your problem so that support could investigate this exception with details.

Comment: I have reported your problem internally and this issue could be caused by the `private audience` option. Please read the progress in your MSDN forum thread for more details: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/e1f84934-45a6-43c9-8b33-4f138ae38db5/loadlistinginformationasync-0x80190194-not-found-404?forum=windowsstore.